# Problem with avatar must be an image. In laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, image, validation

Before posting this question of mine I checked the similar problems but it doesn't solved my problem.

On my form I have the encrypt type

```
<form action="{{ route('user.update_avatar') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    ...
</form>
```

Here's my validator

```
    $request->validate([
        'avatar' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'
    ]);
```

Here's the properties of the image which my form is **accepting**

[image]

Here's the image that gives the **error**

[image]

it puzzles me because they're both PNG but the other has an issues even though the PNG is included in my validator. The Error says,

[image]

Please help me solve this puzzle. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: does it make a difference .png versus .PNG ? I notice these are different

Comment: What generates the specific words; "The avatar failed to upload"?

Answer (score 0):

You should check your php.ini settings.  Default is that uploads can only be 2M max

You need to check upload_max_filesize and post_max_size and make sure they are large enough to accommodate your uploads

Note that in php.ini, sizes are expressed as 4M, 5M etc (don't add the B)

Comment: Thanks again Snapey. The upload_max_filesize is set higher than that. And actually we just add the resize function(thanks to you!). Any other thoughts?

Comment: I just check the upload_max_file is 512M.

Comment: check both values

Comment: both set to 256M. I made a new comparison, a jpg file with only 50kb is not accepting while the other jpg file with 1M is accepting. :(